# Toggle button that will hide/unhide columns within a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below toggle button sub that works;

```
Private Sub Toggle_Unused_Click()
    Dim xAddress As String
    xAddress = "DR:FI"

Call KeyOpen 'unprotects the sheet
If Toggle_Unused.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
    'This returns a value to my notes tab.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").Cells(5, 11).Value = "Hidden"
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
    'This returns a value to my notes tab.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").Cells(5, 11).Value = "Visible"
End If
'This will record how many times the button has been used.
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").Cells(9, 8).Value = _
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").Cells(9, 8).Value + 1
Call KeyLock 'protects the sheet
End Sub
```

Then I updated the code to look like this-

```
Private Sub Toggle_Unused_Click() 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'This will unprotect the sheet
    Call ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").All_Sheets_UnProtect("Notes")

    If Toggle_Unused.Value Then
        Application.ActiveSheet.Range("NAMED_RANGE").Columns.Hidden = True
        'This will return a value to my notes tab.
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").Cells(5, 11).Value = "Hidden"
    Else
        Application.ActiveSheet.Range("NAMED_RANGE").Columns.Hidden = False
        'This will return a value to my notes tab.
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").Cells(5, 11).Value = "Visible"
    End If
    'This will track how many times the button has been used.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").Cells(9, 8).Value = _
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").Cells(9, 8).Value + 1
    'This will protect the sheet
    Call ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").All_Sheets_Protect ("Notes")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'This will close the user form.
    Control_Buttons.Hide

End Sub
```

I have updated to use a named range because my sheet keeps growing with new columns and I am trying to limit how many declared columns I have in my code. I have four of these in a user form that each toggle a different section of sheet(Master).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes")` 5 times, throw that into a variable or use `CodeName` property - View Properties window (F4) and the `(Name)` field can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("mySheet")` and instead just use `mySheet`.

You don't need to `Call` subs, it's obsolete. Instead just use `Sub argument, argument`

As far as troubleshooting the second, that's not really [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here because it's not working. But what is -

```
Call ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Notes").All_Sheets_UnProtect("Notes")
```

You were using

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden
```

and then changed to

```
Range("NAMED_RANGE").Columns.Hidden
```

It works for me. If your sheet is changing, it might fail because you don't specify the sheet.

Comment: I wasn't sure which side this topic falls under. Since the first code does work, and the second part demonstrates what I'd like to do. Although it is a failed attempt, so maybe I should have posted on the other side.

Comment: `All_Sheets_Unprotect("Notes")` is my updated sub that uses a cell value on **Sheet("Notes")**  to unlock the sheet(s). The same goes for `All_Sheets_Protect("Note")`

Comment: That is correct. I'm not sure why though, but the second one will work once or twice, but then won't do anything except close the user form and adjusts the count on **Notes**

Comment: Figures it was something simple like that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It was the sheet? You should fix it and flag it to reopen - I'm sure others might have some insight.

Comment: Quick question, if I have a code that works, but I want to change how it works, would that be a question for here or the other side of this site? I have a code that can find images and put them onto the sheet, but I want to find a way to have it pull images from something like an FTP server or like a Dropbox URL instead of a file path.

Comment: That would be stackoverflow - "I tried to do x but I need to do y, this is what I've tried"